# (iphone) Bluetooth networking is not supported on the original iPhone?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

Apple [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html) doc says:
Bluetooth networking is not supported on the original iPhone.

What is original iPhone here?

Thank you

Comment: Please refer to [http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647) for various iPhone / iPod generations and their Bluetooth support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original iPhone - the first iPhone released.  It was succeeded by the iPhone 3G.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_%28original%29

> The iPhone (pronounced /ˈaɪfoʊn/, EYE-fohn)—retroactively labeled the original iPhone, iPhone 2G, or iPhone EDGE—was the first generation of iPhone designed and marketed by Apple Inc. and was succeeded by the iPhone 3G. It was announced on January 9, 2007[9] after months of rumors and speculation.[10] It was introduced in the United States on June 29, 2007 before being marketed in Europe. It featured quad-band GSM with GPRS and EDGE.
>
> The original iPhone no longer receives software updates from Apple; its final iOS firmware version was 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The default iPhone device is not having default bluetooth functionality as seen in other mobiles, where you can connect to other devices and share files. But it iPhone, you can by default only get connected with the headsets. But using GameKit, we can create a connection and share data between two iPhone devices. That statement should mean this much only, nothing else.